# Query string when Redirect from www.example.com

Tags: redirect

I want to maintain the query string when redirecting from one url to another

for example:

1. A user try to land on the site with URL www.example.com?query=string
2. The user should be redirected to
   www.example.com/us/home?query=string

No other changes are needed than keep the query string when redirecting.

Please suggest some solution. I am thinking of if it can be done at apache level with use of cookies.

Comment: Please post what you've tried, and how it has not worked. Till then it is just another "give me teh codez" question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache server, This can be done easily by adding a RewriteRule to htaccess.

1.Create an htaccess file in the root folder

2.Then add the following Rules :

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
  RewriteRule ^$ /us/home/ [NC,L,R]
```

The rule above will redirect

```
example.com/?query_string
```

to

```
example.com/us/home/?query_string
```

appending the old query strings to the new url.

Reference :

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks... I have tried your solution but it results in many redirect error. we have also posted this question on another account in a better way where you can look and answer on it for my help.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541503/redirection-using-a-query-string-and-cookies-based)

Comment: @ajay sorry forgot to add a question mark at the end of the target path, we use question mark to discard the old query strings, see the edit.

Comment: as per my knowledge ? is used if we don't want any query string in the result URL. Have you checked the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541503/redirection-using-a-query-string-and-cookies-based

Comment: @ajay that's true. sorry I misunderstood the question I have rollbacked it to the orignal version. Your other rules might be causing this error.