# redirection using a query string and cookies based

Tags: redirect

I want to maintain the query string when redirecting from one url to another

for example:

A user try to land on the site with URL www.abc.com?query=string

Currently it is redireted to the **www.abc.com/us/home** where us is the country name which is redirected by default or by using cookies which can be uk,jp,AU etc.

but i want to be redirected like **www.abc.com/us/home?query=string** without removing the query string string.

I am hoping that it can be done using the apache. In case you require some more info, please let me know.

Comment: I tried using below thing **RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+**  
_RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [NC,L,R]_   but it results in many redirection error.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest some solution?